# Does a circle give the largest smallest distance between two points that bisecting the perimeter

Tags: geometry, geometric-topology, combinatorial-geometry

The title may seem a bit confusing, let's use math notation.

Let $c:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a simple closed curve parametrized by length. A pair of points on the curve that bisect the perimeter means any pair in the form $(c(t),c(t+\frac{L}{2}))$ where $L$ is the total length of $c$. Now I am interested in the smallest distance between those pairs, i.e. $$\inf_{t\in[0,{L/2})}|c(t)-c(t+L/2)|.$$
Let's call this smallest bisection length.
Now it seems that fixing $L$, the shape that maximizes the smallest bisection length is the circle with radius $L/(2\pi)$. So, is this true?

Any help will be appreciated! Another question may be related to this is what shape will give the maximum area given a fixed perimeter, whose answer is a circle.

Comment: That can't be. You can take the rope of length $L$ and cram it inside a disc of radius $\epsilon$ still being a simple curve, for every $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: Maybe it's a circle if the curve is required to enclose a convex region?

Comment: @JessicaMcRae, Thank you. You are totally right about this question. I confused myself before and wrote "find the shape of smallest largest bisection length". In fact the correct version should be "find the shape of largest smallest bisection length". I am really sorry about that. Do you have any thought on the problem now?

Comment: Perhaps use "the smallest distance $D$ between those pairs, i.e. $$D = \inf_{t\in[0,{L/2})}|c(t)-c(t+L/2)|$$", and "the shape that maximizes $D/L$"? In the case of a circle, $D$ is a constant (diameter of the circle), and $D/L = 1/\pi$.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Yes. You could also consider the shape that maximize the ratio D/L, but here I choose to fix L and maximize D, which should be equivalent.

Comment: @AltonWang: I meant, perhaps adding a variable name, say $D$, and referring to the variable rather than to "the smallest bisection length", might make the question clearer. (That is, "maximizing $D$" is much easier to read correctly than "maximizing the smallest bisection length", in my humble opinion.)